# Manuscript status changed to editor assigned after under review, what could be the reason?

Tags: peer-review

Recently I submitted minor revision to springer journal. For 3-4 days, the status of my manuscript status was showing to be `Editor Assigned` and after that status changed to `Under Review`. Now status of manuscript is changed to `Editor Assigned` again. What is meaning of this change ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first mission of the editor is to assign reviewers and take a decision depending on their return. Hence the first `Editor Assigned` to `Under Review`. The reason with it is now `Editor Assigned` can be due to several reasons. This depends a lot on the manuscript management system, and the editorial practices.

Either:

- The editor has already received the necessary  reviews, and is taking a decision (perhaps taking another look at your paper)
- The editor has not received the necessary reviews.

The second case may be caused by different situations. Even with a "minor revision", it may happen that:

- not enough of the first round reviewers have responded. Some journals impose a minimum. So he is looking for another reviewer (or doing the review himself), as suggested by @Buzz
- the 2nd round raised more than minor concerns. Sometimes, after the first round, a reviewer notices sometimes more important, and can ask for a major revision (or a reject). So the editor may add another reviewer, to settle the case.

The latter happened to me once as a guest editor. ED1 said major, ED2 said minor. After round 2, ED1 said OK, ED2 said reject. A very painful situation  for everybody.

I wish you are just in the editor decision frame.

Answer (score 2):

It most likely means that the manuscript was send out to a referee, but that the referee ultimately declined to review it.  That happens all the time, and the system may or may not be updated to reflect the fact.  In the case, the system was updated, and since the paper is back with the editor (who still needs to find a reviewer), the posted status reflects that.

Comment: My manuscript was reviewed by two reviewers and one of them accepted my work and second suggested some minor changes. I edited my manuscript according to suggestions of second reviewer. Can he still decline to review my minor revision ?

Comment: @IgotiT It would certainly be unusual to recommend minor revisions then be unwilling to review the revised manuscript, but it can happen.

Comment: I recently had two reviewers that recommended minor changes refused to review my revised manuscript.  Consequently, the editor had to sent it out to two new reviewers.  Unfortunately, they didn't like my paper.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple.The reviews have been completed and the concerned editor has been assigned by the journal manager to evaluate the review report, so that he communicate the same to the corresponding author.No confusion , it is just normal practice

Answer (score 0):

In some situations, it shows that the reviewers are done reviewing and their reports have been sent back to the Academic Editor for final decision. This is why the status shows "Editor assigned".