# Awaiting AE Recommendation to Awaiting AE Assignment

Tags: peer-review, editors

Paper just went to this after review. Any idea what this means in terms of the paper's status at this point?

Answer (score 2):

Odds are this means the AE changed. This could be because the original AE declined the assignment, resigned from the editorial board, is too busy to make a decision, and so on.

See also this question: [Manuscript status changed from “Reviews completed” to “Editor assigned”](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/91221/manuscript-status-changed-from-reviews-completed-to-editor-assigned)